# Stop Unlisted Services

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, lampp

I have just reinstalled LAMPP. When I try starting LAMPP using `/opt/lampp/lampp start`, it says another ftp and mysql daemon is already running along with another web server. I deleted the old instance of LAMPP without stopping all the services. When I use `service --status-all` these services aren't listed.

Is there any way I can stop it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with this : `pkill -f apache; pkill -f httpd`

You can run that on each service you want to stop.

To test if it's still running, try `pgrep -fl <APP_NAME>`.

If it's the case, consider using `pkill -1 -f <APP_NAME>` and if still present `pkill -9 -f <APP_NAME>`. `-9` is the higher signal. Don't use `-9` by default, you will facing problems with not well closed applications (file descriptors and other system stuff)

see `man 7 signal`.

Comment: I'm getting several instances of httpd with different PID but same image name. How would kill using the PID?

Comment: Oh using "httpd" killed all of them.